# strongMan: /var/run/charon.vici doesn't exist

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I was trying to use strongMan to configure strongswan vpn connection. However I encountered the following error:

```
/var/run/charon.vici doesn't exist
```

I have installed `strongswan` and `strongswan-charon` but `/usr/local/libexec/ipsec/charon` doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 2):

strongMan connects to the daemon via [VICI protocol](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Vici), so you need the *vici* plugin, which is shipped by Debian/Ubuntu in the **strongswan-swanctl** package.